Ubuntu 22.04 cups is not working like 20.04/16.04 cups versions
I have a server edition of 22.04 LTS ubuntu in which I have attached a receipt printer that works with CUPS. I have installed the drivers to the cups using lpadmin (+ filters + ppd) but I notice that in ubuntu 22.04 there is a larger top margin than 20.04 or 16.04 where my printer was originally installed.
I can see between 16.04 and 22.04 that the cups versions are having a big gap (2.1.3 against 2.4.1) but I can't debug more to see what's wrong with the margins. I am using the same ppd and the same raster filter in both occasions.

Any file being print (either pdf or postscript) has top margin. Is there any way to debug this?
How can I downgrade the cups in case I want the same functionality?
Any other suggestions?

Note that I don't have full xwindows access, only the application being ran (kiosk mode) so no printing dialogs or setup there. The only thing I can access is cups webinterface.
I have installed 4 printers currently via lpadmin. Star TSP 700, a POS80 Portable printer and cups-pdf. The only issues I have are on star tsp 700 but I have used another printer and still see the same margin issue. POS80 and pdf do not have that.
